# delete function delets the last record from table. js jquery.updated

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamic table which gets values from db. I have a button which onclcik runs the query to delete the record from database. Currently instead of deleteing record(which was clicked )  its deleting the last record available. I am updating from here I figure out the issue when I provide ID to the post somehow the LAST ID is being sent to the query, is there anyway I can delete the ID which was selected.please look at the code for more info

```js
//this is how im creating dynamic table
//just for the test
function() {
 
    });

  });
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>

      </td>
    </tr>

  </thead>
  <tbody id="table"></tbody>
</table>


<button type="button" id="chochk" style="display:none" class="sukuti">delete</button>
```

.

Comment: Where do you set the variable `ad`?

Comment: variable ad is the ID, onclcik button send specific ID to the query and it will delete the row with that ID from DB.

Comment: But you never set it anywhere. What if you check multiple rows, which one should it delete?

Comment: You have a typo here: `this.ckhecked`

Comment: thx I fixed that typo and still it deletes the last record available, currently I am just trying to delete the one row whih every is clicked, but you have very good point I guess I am gonna make a code to select only one box at a time or use radio button

Comment: I don't understand why it deletes anything. You never set `ad`.

Comment: Use radio buttons instead of checkboxes so they can only select one.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you may be better listening directly on the `change` event of the checkbox and then get the value of the `event.target` afterwards? There is something wrong with the way you are getting the variable `ad` in your code i suspect, but without seeing how that is derived it's hard to see why.
The example below shows a simple way to get the value of a checkbox, hopefully this might lead you to the correct answer.

```js
$('.test').on('change', function(e) {
  alert(e.target.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Value of 1: <input type="checkbox" class="test" value="1" /><br />
Value of 2: <input type="checkbox" class="test" value="2" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a checkbox, use a radio button, so the user can only select one at a time. Then in the handler for the delete button, get the value of the checked button and send that to the server.

```js
//this is how im creating dynamic table
//just for the test
function() {
  var table = document.getElementById('tablebody');

  for (var i = 0; i < (test.length); i = i + 2) { //test is an array of values from db
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);

    var cell3 = row.insertCell(-1);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(-1);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(-1);

    cell1.innerHTML = //some html span
    cell2.innerHTML = //some html span

    //this is the checkbox which onclick shows the button
    cell3.innerHTML = '<input type="radio" name="checkbox" class="your" value="ID of current row">';
  }



  ///this is how i am displaying a button on click and also delete function
  $(document).on('click', ".your", function() {
    $('#chochk').show();
  });

  $(".sukuti").click(function() {
    var ad = $(".your:checked").val();
    $.post("test.jsp", {
      id: ad //ad is the ID  which will delete the specifIC ID being clicked
    }, function(data) { //sending a query to delete from db working good 

    });

  });
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>

      </td>
    </tr>

  </thead>
  <tbody id="table"></tbody>
</table>


<button type="button" id="chochk" style="display:none" class="sukuti">delete</button>
```